# filter table based on name attribute in a specific cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which I want to filter based on name attribute which is a specific value . I was trying this but its not working.
I know that this works if a specific text is in the row .

```
$('td').parent('tr:not(:contains("' + value + '"))').hide();
```

I have a row and inside that there is a cell with an image , this image has a name , I want to show hide the row based on this image name .

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="H1.gif" alt="" name="image1"></img></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="H2.gif" alt="" name="image2"></img>/td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is a sample table and ive tried this code also which doesnt wanna work .
I am trying to hide the row which doesnt have the name which is the value .

```
$('td').parent('tr:not(:contains(name=["' + value + '"]))').hide();
```

any help guys .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, below is a working snippet!

```js
var val = "image1";
$("#table").find("img:not([name="+ val +"])").parents("tr").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" name="image1"/></td>
<td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" name="image2"/></td>
<td>Francisco Chang</td>
<td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Adam Can you use this code, replicate the issue in JSFiddle and share?

Comment: i edited your snippet , maybe the body element is the wrong issue here ?

Comment: @Adam The body tag is inside the table, please place the body tag at the top then followed by the table with id `table`

Comment: It worked when i used this format 'img:not([name="' + val + '"])' , instead of doube quotes . strange . anyway great solution

Comment: i have another question for u if its ok , i need to loop inside tr in body and compare depending on a cell value . i tried the following 
            table = document.getElementById("tbody");
            
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

Comment: but i cant get the tr . the array is always empty , tried a bunch of other solutions but nothing worked . any helo appriciated

Comment: @Adam What is the problem actually? can you explain more?

Comment: ok i have a table ,  inside this table i need to loop inside its tbody rows and then scroll automatically to the row that have nearest time to now , time is a cell inside this row

Comment: @Adam Seems like you need to share the code in a new question! since this is totally different requirement!